# Автоподписка на каналы телеграмм

Tags: python, telegram

Разрабатываю бота для телеграмм Python. Бегает по каналам с комментариями и соответственно оставляет комментарии. По немного масштабирую идею. Но, наткнулся в очень неприятную штуку. Каждый раз что бы добавить новый канал для комментариев, на него надо подписаться, только потом пойдут комментарии.

Подскажите кто знает, как решить такую задачку.
Есть текстовый документ с id каналов. Все действие делается через API my.telegram.org

Проделать это надо 1 раз всего, но, аккаунтов много.
Нужна простая реализация подписки по каналам из текстового файла.
За ранее благодарен. Что не пробовал и где только не искал, опыта не хватает реализовать самому. Новичок.
Сам скрипт, сильно не ругайте только учусь...

```
while True:
    TEXTS = linecache.getline('comments.txt', random.randint(0, 70))
    PUBLIC = linecache.getline('canals.txt', random.randint(0, 51))
    public = app.get_chat(PUBLIC)
    chat = public.linked_chat  
    for msg in app.get_history(chat.id, limit=100):

        if (msg.from_user is None
                and msg.forward_from_chat.id == public.id):
            if msg.forward_from_message_id % COMMENT_EVERY_N != 0:
                print(f'Пропускаем message_id={msg.message_id},'
                    f' так как комментируе каждое {COMMENT_EVERY_N}')
                continue
            if str(msg.forward_from_message_id) in processed_messages:
                print(f'Пропускаем уже обработанное message_id={msg.message_id}')
                continue
           
            processed_messages[str(msg.forward_from_message_id)] = True

            print(f'Обработка message_id={msg.message_id}')

            text = TEXTS
            app.send_message(chat.id, text, reply_to_message_id=msg.message_id) 

            break

    print('Ставим на паузу')
    time.sleep(60 * 4)
```

Comment: Подскажите, решили свой вопрос? Интересен ваш софт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для этого библиотеку Telethon

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html?highlight=Subscribe%20to%20channel#id9